# How to catch un-handled errors with PHPseclib?

Tags: php, phpseclib

Let's say I have the following piece of code.

To test this, I change the server IP to mimic the error messages. The IP below doesn't exist so the `Unhandled Exception` message is: `Cannot connect to 10.199.1.7. Error 113. No route to host`

This displays an ugly screen with PHP code. Is it possible to catch this error?

```
try {
      $ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.199.1.7');        
  if (!$ssh->login('deploy', $key)) {
       throw new Exception("Failed login");
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
     ???
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looked through library.

```
user_error('Connection closed by server', E_USER_NOTICE);
```

It triggers errors. You can handle those errors using http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

e.g.

```
// Your file.php
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.199.1.7');        
$ssh->login('deploy', $key);

// bootstrap.php
// This will catch all user notice errors!!!
set_error_handler ('errorHandler', E_USER_NOTICE)

function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    echo 'Error';
    // Whatever you want to do.
}
```

Comment: Having a hard time figuring this out. How would i go about implementing this into my existing code above?

Comment: So basically include the `boostrap.php` file inside `file.php` and it should work?

Comment: Good call on the user_errors. I went Google-ing when I saw this question and landed on someone's forked implementation on Github, using exceptions, rather than the official one on SourceForge. My answer is 100% wrong so I marked it for deletion. Thanks for the catch and +1

Comment: Np, I found git hub version first too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ in front of you function call. [@ operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: Using @ is always a bad idea!

Comment: this is called silencing errors, and that's not a way to fix a problem, it's only to ignore it